# Task of NSManagedObject, NSManagedObjectContext, NSEntityDescription, NSPredicate, NSPersistentStoreCoordinator

Tags: nspredicate, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsentitydescription

i am new in ios field, read the tutorial related to above class from apple official website.
But i can't understand what is actually job of the NSManagedObject, NSManagedObjectContext, NSEntityDescription, NSPredicate given class. 
so please help me.
Thank You.

Comment: Link to the tutorial: [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/). Please take a look before voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple should put a link to [Core Data Core Competencies](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Devpedia-CoreData/coreDataOverview.html) in the tutorial.